# not all polygons showing up in qgis 2.0

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2

I am working with the block group shp files that I got from tiger 2010. When I bring in the shp files some of the block groups show up, but this is spotty.

I have adjusted the CRS and still nothing.

I have tried highlighting everything and checked the attributes table; all of the polygons seem to be there but only about 50 are highlighted.

When I tell it to zoom to the layer extent it goes to the area that looks like it would encompass the entire state.

I have also re-downloaded the zip file and extracted them but with no success.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the spatial index files, .sbn, .sbx or create a new spatial index.